# Не могу найти решение ошибки PHP <-- неопределенный индекс: cityval в C: \ OpenServer \ domains \ citymaps \ index.php в строке 15 -->

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Помогите пожалуйста делаю связной список на PHP и вывод ошибку -- неопределенный индекс: cityval в C: \ OpenServer \ domains \ citymaps \ index.php в строке 15 -- Не могу понять что нужно исправить вроде все написанно не могу найти причину((

Вот код index.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once "db.php";
require_once "function.php";




$city = selectCity();



if($_POST['cityval']){
   print_r ($return);
   exit("TEST");
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,=">
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Зависимые списки</title>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script srs="lists.js"></script>
   <style>
      form div{margin: 0 0 15px 0;}
      #divstreet, #divhouse {display: none;}
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <form action="index.php"method="POST">
      <div>
         <select name="city" id="city">
            <option value="0">Выберите город</option>
            <?php foreach($city as $cit):?>
               <option value="<?=$cit['id_city']?>"><?=$cit['city_name']?></option>
            <?php endforeach?>
         </select>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div id="divstreet">
         <select disabled name="street" id="street"></select>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div id="divhouse">
         <select disabled name="house" id="house"></select>
      </div>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

вот код JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#city").change(function () {
      var cityval = parseInt($("#city").val());
      selectCity(cityval);
   });
});

function selectStreet(cityval) {
   var street = $("#street");

   if (cityval > 0) {
      $("#divstreet").fadeIn("slow");
      street.attr("disabled", false);
      street.load(
         "index.php",
         {cityval: cityval}
      );

   }

}
```

вот код функций

```
<?php


function selectCity(){
   global $db;
   $query = "SELECT * FROM city";
   $res = mysqli_query($db, $query);
   $city = array();
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
      $city[] = $row;
   }
   return $city;
}

function selectStreet(){
   global $db;
   $cityval = (int) $_POST['cityval'];
   $query = "SELECT * FROM `street` WHERE street = $cityval";
   $res = mysqli_query($db, $query);
   $return = "<option value='0'>Выберите улицу</option>";
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
      $return .= "<option value='{$row['id_street']}'name>{$row['street']}></option>";
   }
   return $return;
}
```

Comment: А где Вы в форме `cityval` передаете на POST? Его нигде нет, поэтому и пишет, что нет значения по индексу.

Comment: А как его можно туда передать?

Comment: в js написано `selectCity(cityval);` а функция называется `selectStreet` или где-то потеряли функцию ещё?

Comment: Я обычно пишу условие так, чтобы проверялась переменная на существование вначале. Примерно так: `if(isset($_POST['cityval']) && $_POST['cityval'])`